# New Available on appstore Badge?

Tags: ios7

I noticed a lot of website using a kind of "new" but yet unofficial "Available on Appstore" Badge. Like this one:

[appstore badge](http://www.kooldiner.com/images/common/App_Store_Badge.png)

Where does that come from ? Even Techcrunch is using it, but I don't find the resource anywhere on Apple website.

So is it official or not?
If yes how to get the official asset?
If no, How is that much people are switching to this specific custom one?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at Apple's App Store [marketing guidelines](https://developer.apple.com/app-store/marketing/guidelines/#legal).

Comment: I don't see how that answers the question. Could you please summarize or quote here the part of that document that explains that image?

Comment: Indeed those guidelines emphasize the fact that less and less people are following them...